# is it possible to get sonarqube 8.6 exitcode from terminal based on analysis results?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner

Hi all I'm on linux and want to run sonarqube locally and based on the analysis result get exit code

- So for example if 0 errors in code analysis then exit code 0
- If it has 1 or more error in code analysis then exit code != 0

I run SQ server from docker-compose like this:

```
version: "3"
services:
  sonarqube:
    container_name: sonarqube
    image: sonarqube:latest
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9092:9092"
```

and then with node I run `sonarqube-scanner`:

```
const sonarqubeScanner = require('sonarqube-scanner');
sonarqubeScanner({
    serverUrl: 'http://localhost:9000',
    options : {
        'sonar.sources': '.',
        'sonar.inclusions' : 'src/**',
    }
}, () => {});
```

Finally I get success on console but no exit codes:

```
INFO: CPD Executor 4 files had no CPD blocks
INFO: CPD Executor Calculating CPD for 3 files
INFO: CPD Executor CPD calculation finished (done) | time=11ms
INFO: Analysis report generated in 74ms, dir size=97 KB
INFO: Analysis report compressed in 46ms, zip size=21 KB
INFO: Analysis report uploaded in 34ms
INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://localhost:9000/dashboard?id=foobar
INFO: Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
INFO: More about the report processing at http://localhost:9000/api/ce/task?id=example
INFO: Analysis total time: 18.668 s
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 19.616s
INFO: Final Memory: 12M/50M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[11:10:42] Analysis finished.
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't practical for the sonar-scanner to return the scan results, because there are many details that a client might want to see.  At the completion of the scan in the sonarqube server, a background task is run that produces the basic statistics based on the guidelines in the quality gate set in the project.

Typically, the SonarQube project has a "Webhook" value that specifies a url to post the background task results to, and that url is usually in Jenkins.

In a Jenkins scripted pipeline job, the "waitForQualityGate()" pipeline step is used to wait for that webhook call to be received.

Comment: It's worth to note that quality gate status is computed on the server side, so it is not available to sonar-scanner anyway.